# Input field with attached text to the right

Tags: javascript, input

I'm doing a fancy comment list on my project, structured like this:

[image]

As you see, there's a comments list and at his bottom there's an input field (textarea) to submit a comment. Note that there's the current username attached to the right (let's call it a simple static appended text).

[image]

I just found [this little JS](http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/NvynC/) to make an input field resize automatically by adapting it to the content.

```
function resizeInput() {
    $(this).attr('size', $(this).val().length);
}
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(resizeInput).each(resizeInput);
```

But it's not enough. I need it for a textarea and I want it to behave correctly when a comment is long enough to wrap on another line. By definition, the input field is a box, and it obviously acts badly compared to what I want:

[image]

Instead, this should be the right behavior:

[image]

I looked everywhere and I can't think any way to implement this. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/) is a good plugin for textarea. But it using jQuery.

usage simple as always.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('textarea').autosize();   
});
```

Comment: This won't do what @AndroidGuy wants, it will behave just like his current solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this

**NOTE: No check for selection and bound to document. Exercise for the reader to bind to a specific field and swap it for a span**

[image]

[**FiDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/zdy5hhL3/)

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  var char = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
  if (e.which==13) char = '<br/>'; // needs to handle backspace etc.
  $("#textfield").append(char);
  $("#hiddenfield").val($("#textfield").text()); // or .html if you want the BRs
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

using

```
<span id="textfield"></span> - by My Username
```

If you make the field contenteditable you will get this in Chrome so some additional CSS may be needed

[image]

Comment: This doesn't support text selection, copy-cut-paste, etc. Also, it should be attached to some specific DOM node, not the whole document, otherwise the field will be populated even when it's not focused.

Comment: Yes it does if you program it to do so. This is not e-lancing so I just posted my proof of concept. If he likes it we can take it further

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) attribute:

```
<span contenteditable="true">comment</span> by <span class="userName">someone</span>
```

It is supported in [practically all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable). Using the right CSS, you can underline the content and also limit the width.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<span>` with `contenteditable` ([supported in IE too](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable)). Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/goabqjLn/2/

```
<span contenteditable>Insert a comment...</span> by My Username
```

Then, using JavaScript, attach an event listener that mirrors the inner text of the span into a hidden input field, so it gets submitted with your `<form>`.

**Edit**: I have updated the fiddle to also include the JS code. Here is the updated code:

```
<span class="editor" id="editor" contenteditable data-placeholder="Insert a comment...">Insert a comment...</span> by My Username
<!-- Hide this textarea in production: --> 
<textarea type="text" id="comment"></textarea>
```

And the JS:

```
function mirror() {    
    var text = $('#editor').html().trim()
       .replace('&nbsp;', ' ')
       .replace(/<br(\s*)\/*>/ig, '\n') // replace single line-breaks
       .replace(/<[p|div]\s/ig, '\n$0') // add a line break before all div and p tags
       .replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");   // remove any remaining tags    

    $('#comment').val(text);
}

$('#editor').focus(function () { 
    var editor = $(this);

    if (editor.text() == editor.attr('data-placeholder')) {
        editor.text('');
    }
}).blur(function () { 
    var editor = $(this);

    if (editor.text() == editor.attr('data-placeholder')) {
        editor.text(editor.attr('data-placeholder'));
    }
}).blur(mirror).keyup(mirror);
```

Comment: Well, this is a good solution. But it is submittable in a form?

Comment: @AndroidGuy Only by using JavaScript.

Comment: By itself, no, that's why you need some JS to mirror the content of the span into a hidden form field.

Comment: @AndroidGuy I have updated my answer to include the JS too :)

Comment: When pressing enter in Chrome, the -my username is moved to under the text and the whole field splits. Very ugly

Comment: I didn't tought about the hidden mirror field. Looks the best solution. I'm giving it a try, thanks!

Comment: @AndroidGuy no problem :). If you want it to not depend on having JS enabled, you can show the normal textarea by default, and hide it using the same JS that then shows the contenteditable span and attaches the event listeners.

Comment: Hi. I just tried your script. I noticed that if there's no text the span acts weird. How can it be fixed?

Comment: And how can I prevent the "enter" key from doing a line-break?

Comment: Preventing newlines is easy, just add a check for the key code for Enter (13) on keydown, and return false: http://jsfiddle.net/goabqjLn/3/